# What happens to questions that aren't revealed during Jeopardy?

Tags: jeopardy

Every now and again, we don't get through all of the questions on the board during *Jeopardy!*  Many of these questions have been well researched. So my question is (in true Jeopard style):

**This is what happens to questions that aren't revealed during the show**

Comment: Sadly, question shelters are already crowded with unused questions, so any questions not used during an episode are euthanized by Alex Trebec.

Comment: @R.J.MacReady That's why I prefer Bob Barker's approach of spaying or neutering questions on the price is right

Answer (score 54, accepted):

According to [this interview with **Alex Trebek**](http://www.deseretnews.com/article/134326/JEOPARDY-BOOK-GOES-BEHIND-THE-SCENES.html?pg=all) promoting ***The Jeopardy! Book: The Answers, the Questions, the Facts, and the Stories of the Greatest Game Show in History***:

> "We save all unused material, although sometimes an answer that isn't
>   used one day will turn up later under a different category."

**Billy Wisse**, the head writer for *Jeopardy!*, says the same in [an interview with The AV Club](http://www.avclub.com/article/whats-it-be-one-jeopardy-clue-writers-216093):

> AVC: How many questions get thrown out upon review?
>
> BW: Well, in every category one is going to get thrown out, and then
>   there’s always an extra there for emergencies or technical problems.
>   And so two clues out of every seven get thrown out, but **they could get
>   used later if you write that same category again** or you really like
>   that clue and you want to write around it. So a lot of clues get
>   thrown out, but some of them come back again. But **we have thousands
>   and thousands and thousands of unused clues**, and most of them will
>   never see the light of day.

Comment: I doubt we're going to get a better answer than this; great work!

Comment: I wish this answer was in the form of a question and the question written as "This is what happens to questions that aren't revealed during Jeopardy"

Comment: I was a little confused by the "in every category one is going to get thrown out" comment.  Elsewhere in the interview, it's explained that a writer submits seven clues for a category, and the head writer selects six to be used and discards the remaining one.